# find path excluding doesn't work when permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, find

There is some strange behavior while excluding path from [`find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

```
find ~ -not -path "~/sandboxes/*" -name 'some-file.vmdk'
```

gives:

```
/home/user/VMs/win/some-file.vmdk
find: ‘/home/user/sandboxes/debian7.amd64.buildd/root/...’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/user/sandboxes/debian7.amd64.buildd/var/...’: Permission denied
```

What's wrong?

P.S. unfortunately `-prune` doesn't work too:

```
find ~ -path "/home/user/sandboxes/*" -prune -o -name 'some-file.vmdk'
```

gives more weird results:

```
/home/user/nemu_vm/win/some-file.vmdk
/home/user/sandboxes/debian7.amd64.buildd
/home/user/sandboxes/debian9.amd64.buildd
```

[Useful link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210042/how-to-exclude-a-directory-in-find-command)

Comment: Could you replace `-path "~/sandboxes/*"` with `-path "$HOME/sandboxes/*"`

Comment: @Inian there is no effect. The same output

Comment: Can you confirm you are you looking for regular files named `some-file.vmdk` only? It may be useful to state explicitly what the expected output is, we may wonder if you want the path `/home/user/sandboxes` (not its content) to be printed or not.

Comment: @fra-san Yep, it's about regular files it this case. I want `find` not to even enter `/home/user/sandboxes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your command

```
find ~ -path "/home/user/sandboxes/*" -prune -o -name 'some-file.vmdk'
```

prints

```
/home/user/sandboxes/debian7.amd64.buildd
/home/user/sandboxes/debian9.amd64.buildd
```

because the default action when no action is supplied is to output the found pathnames.  The above pathnames are found, and then those paths are pruned.  Pruning a search path does not exclude these pathnames from being printed.

However, if you add `-print` to the very end, as in

```
find "$HOME" -path "$HOME/sandboxes" -prune -o -name 'some-file.vmdk' -print
```

then those pathnames would *not* be printed.  This is because now you have an explicit action (the `-print`), so no default actions are triggered. The `-print` only applies to the right hand side of `-o`.

Note that the `*` is not needed, and that the variable `$HOME` is easier to work with than `~`, especially in scripts.

---

Your first command,

```
find ~ -not -path "~/sandboxes/*" -name 'some-file.vmdk'
```

very likely does not work as `~` is not expanded within quotes.

Assuming you used `$HOME` instead, it also does not prune the search path, which means it would still enter `~/sandboxes`, but it would never print any pathnames from beneath that path.  Since it enters the directory, it would still give you the permission errors when it reaches the inaccessibly directories.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! BTW `find "$HOME" -path "$HOME/sandboxes" -prune -type f -o -name 'some-file.vmdk'` helped too as @fra-san suggested

Comment: @z0lupka Please note that what I wrote in my previous comment is a bit ugly. Semantically, the correct form would be `find "$HOME" -path "$HOME/sandboxes" -prune -false -o -name 'some-file.vmdk'`, where `false` is used to prevent any action when `prune` succeeds (sorry for this invasion, Kusalananda).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way :

```
find ~ \! -path "*/sandboxes/*" -name 'some-file.vmdk'
```

Or with -prune :

```
find ~ -path "*/sandboxes" -prune -o -name 'some-file.vmdk'
```

but can't find a way to remove the print of ~/sandboxes

Comment: unfortunately didn't help